# Unable to access gnome terminal on ubuntu 22.04 LTS server with ubuntu-desktop installed

Tags: server, 22.04, gnome-terminal, remote-desktop, vnc

Hi I have setup tigervncserver by following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-desktop-aws#3-configuring-the-vnc-server on Ubuntu server running one AWS ec2 metal instance, but i have trouble running gnome-terminal.

Here is my vnc configuration.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-122-54:~$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Here is what I'm seeing in vnc.log

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-122-54:~$ cat /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ip-10-0-122-54:1.log 
21/10/23 12:00:39 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
21/10/23 12:00:39 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
21/10/23 12:00:39 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
21/10/23 12:00:39 All Rights Reserved.
21/10/23 12:00:39 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
21/10/23 12:00:39 Desktop name 'X' (ip-10-0-152-74:1)
21/10/23 12:00:39 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
21/10/23 12:00:39 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
21/10/23 12:00:39 Listening for HTTP connections on TCP port 5801
21/10/23 12:00:39   URL http://ip-10-0-152-74:5801
/home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: 11: vncconfig: not found
/home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: 13: gnome-settings-daemon: not found
metacity-Message: 12:00:41.063: could not find XKB extension.

(metacity:3255): metacity-WARNING **: 12:00:41.066: Failed to create compositor: Missing composite extension required for compositing
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".

(gnome-panel:3253): gnome-panel-WARNING **: 12:00:41.391: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:3256): WARNING **: 12:01:31.360: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /home/ubuntu/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:3256): WARNING **: 12:01:31.360: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /home/ubuntu/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Nautilus-Share-Message: 12:01:31.407: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

21/10/23 12:02:01 Got connection from client 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:01 Using protocol version 3.8
21/10/23 12:02:10 Full-control authentication passed by 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:10 Pixel format for client 10.0.7.237:
21/10/23 12:02:10   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
21/10/23 12:02:10   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
21/10/23 12:02:10   no translation needed
21/10/23 12:02:10 Using zlib encoding for client 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:10 Using compression level 1 for client 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:10 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:10 Enabling cursor position updates for client 10.0.7.237
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131072
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131071
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131070
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131069
21/10/23 12:02:10 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -309
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "X-Resource" missing on display ":1".
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```